# Check if string contains only digits and dots (.)

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to use a fields as a String and I want that the user should be able to add only digits and dots. and I am looking on the net and is hard to find something, can anyone give me a hand I would really appreciate that. Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: All the solutions which simply use patterns, still **allow** the user to type restricted symbols, and then mark them as invalid.

If you'd like to **prevent** typing invalid characters, then you can use the solution below.

It's a component that doesn't even allow to type any other character than digits and dots,
and always makes sure that the input is a number before inserting the character into the input.

Also, it doesn't allow to type invalid numbers like "45..3" "3.4..4" using those characters.
Bonus Feature 1: It works fine with mobile (since doesn't look for Keydown/Keyup events).
Bonus Feature 2: It doesn't allow to copy paste invalid text as well.

```
import { Component, Input, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';

import {
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  NG_VALIDATORS,
  Validator,
  FormControl,
  ValidationErrors,
  ControlValueAccessor
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'numeric-input',
  template: '<input type="text" inputmode="numeric" [placeholder]="placeHolderText" [ngModel]="inputValue" (input)="onInputChange($event)">',
  providers: [
  {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => NumericInputComponent),
    multi: true
  },
  {
    provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => NumericInputComponent),
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class NumericInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator {
  @Input() public placeHolderText = '';
  @Input() public isRequired = false;

  public inputValue: string;

  public onInputChange(event: any): void {
    const newValue = event.target.value;
    if (!this.isValidInput(newValue)) {
      // Invalid input detected. Resetting to previous value
      event.target.value = this.inputValue;
    } else if (newValue !== this.inputValue) {
      // New valid input detected.
      this.inputValue = newValue;
      this.propagateChange(this.inputValue);
    }
  }

  //#region Custom validation

  // Note: Used the mechanism described in the link below
  // https://medium.com/@tarik.nzl/angular-2-custom-form-control-with-validation-json-input-2b4cf9bc2d73

  // Called for setting the initial value
  public writeValue(value: string): void {
    if (this.isValidInput(value) && this.inputValue !== value) {
      this.inputValue = value;
    }
  }

  // Validates the form, returns null when valid else the validation object
  public validate(formControl: FormControl): ValidationErrors {
    return (this.isRequired && !this.inputValue) ? { required: true } : null;
  }

  // Registers function that will be fired when changes are made.
  public registerOnChange(callbackFunction: (newValue: string) => void): void {
    this.propagateChange = callbackFunction;
  }

  // Non-implemented method which are required by the validator interface
  public registerOnTouched(callbackFunction: () => void): void { }

  // The method set in registerOnChange to emit changes back to the form
  private propagateChange = (newValue: string) => { };

  private isValidInput(value: string): boolean {
    // Note: ParseInt is not recommended as it will convert "222aa" -> "222" and assume as valid
    return !isNaN(Number(value));
  }

  //#endregion Custom validation
}
```

Usage:

```
<numeric-input [(ngModel)]="ModelNameHere">
</numeric-input>
```

Note: You might consider moving out the html template of the component outside the component.ts file to separate html file and use templateUrl instead (like it's done in the samples below).

Here is a quick [code sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9tfzhq) and [demo](https://angular-9tfzhq.stackblitz.io) on stackblitz just in case it's needed.
And here is a [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-rnnxqm) for angular material.

Comment: this is an amazing solution but, when I put a wrong like it gets clean all the output, I see it stack it isn't happening, and I check all the steps but still I get the form clean .

Comment: That's strange... Could you please provide more details on what you are putting there that it cleans the output?

Comment: I fixed, in fact, was my mistake, but I have a question, if I create a new component so I can use it other places how can I used it in this case, can you give me a hint please, cause I am not so good, I tried something but didn't work , and  i don 't know what was wrong cause I didn't get any error

Comment: I guess you have forgotten to add the component to the module where it's used.
P.S. In the stackblitz code sample you might notice that I've imported "NumericInputComponent" to "app.module.ts" and added to the "declarations" section there.

Comment: Yeah I see, but I did that also, but the problem is at HTML file at the input fields, how do I used it there can you provide me an example, and also i accept your answer is an amazing work mate

Comment: I've just updated the stackblitz sample and put the usage of that component inside the "test.component.html". Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198990/discussion-between-ilia-tapia-and-just-shadow).

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you to use `regex` to validate the string. The below regex will allow only digits and .

```
/[^.0-9]+/g
```

I you want to validate only digits, then you can use below expression.

```
/[^0-9]+/g
```

Feel free to ask queries...

Answer (score 1):

It will be good if you use Regular Expression to check this.
Please try below RegEx.

```
(?!0+$)^[0-9].*$
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly is valid and what not. So my example test when there are only dots, only digits, it can starts with zeros etc.

However regular expressions can do that job.

// Edit: more specific regex according to comments

```js
var reg = new RegExp('^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*$')
reg.test("0") // true
reg.test("0.") // false
reg.test("0.1") // true
reg.test("0...1.2") // false
reg.test("00.0.888.6") // true
reg.test(".0.8.6") // false
reg.test("01.2.a3") // false - there is "a"
```

Comment: it can't start with. , should be at least one digit before using. Can you try this please

Comment: hey I test it and there is one small problem, can fix it that will not allow double ..
`reg.test(1..2) //false` and i will accept your answer

Comment: Not so easy... There can be only 1 dot? Or more dots, but not in a row? And it can ends with dot? Or must end with a number? What is minimum length and maximum length? Give me more what I can handle. Some examples.. Update your original question and put what is correct and what not. Don't forget to include edge cases

Comment: ok so I can have more that one (.) but not in a row, it can't start or end with (.) , for the number the only thing is that can be smaller than zero, so `min=`.

Comment: Check now. No dots in a row. Basically regular says there must be at least some digits. If there is a dot, after dot must be at least one digit. The last part can repeat multiple times

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198932/discussion-between-ilia-tapia-and-arxeiss).

Answer (score 1):

First create directive for decimal places in typescript like this:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDecimalNumber]'
})
export class DecimalNumberDirective {
  private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^\d*\.?\d*$/g);
  private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', '-', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight', 'Del', 'Delete'];
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }
  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement.value);
    // Allow Backspace, tab, end, and home keys
    if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
      return;
    }
    let current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    const position = this.el.nativeElement.selectionStart;
    const next: string = [current.slice(0, position), event.key == 'Decimal' ? '.' : event.key, current.slice(position)].join('');
    if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

Inject Directive in your app.module.ts. In your html use that directive like this:

```
<input type="textbox" [(ngModel)]="InputValue" appDecimalNumber>
```

Answer (score 1):

Call this function in keypress event and pass the event. I'm using this function in my project also and it works fine.

```
numberOnlyWithFloat(event): boolean {
  const charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
  console.log("charCode ::: ", charCode);
  if (charCode == 46) {
    console.log("true...");
    return true;
  }
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In Angular2 below code may help u out.
Html
<input name="username" [ngModel]="user.username" [pattern]="unamePattern" #uname="ngModel"> Now display validation error message.
    <div *ngIf="uname.errors?.pattern"> 
       User name not valid.
    </div> 

Typescript
unamePattern = "[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*";
```